# Google App Engine Launcher on Windows 8.1

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, windows-8.1

I am running Windows 8.1 64 bit on a core I7 laptop. I am running Python 2.7.6 with the GoogleAppEngine-1.8.7 installed. IIS 8.5 is also installed with the PHP manager extension

I have PHP 5.4.10 also installed in the C:\PHP directory

I had already created 3 Wordpress apps locally successfully (about a week ago) and when I ran them in the Google App Engine Launcher Browser everything was fine until 2 days ago.

Now when I start the apps and launch the browser on the locally host on port 8080 I get a blank screen.

This is the contents of the log file:

> ```
> INFO     2013-11-12 04:31:39,665 dispatcher.py:171] Starting module "default" running at: http://locally host:8080
> INFO     2013-11-12 04:31:39,667 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://locally host:8000
> INFO     2013-11-12 04:31:50,822 module.py:608] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
> ```

contents of app.yaml:

```
application: icefishingco
version: wp
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
  secure: always

- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-login.php
  script: wordpress/wp-login.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
  login: admin

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /wp-(.+).php
  script: wordpress/wp-\1.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php
```

Contents of cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: wordpress cron tasks
  url: /wp-cron.php
  schedule: every 2 hours
```

contents of my php.ini:

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name, gc_enabled"
```

System Environment variable:

```
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\php;c:\python27;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\
```

What, if anything, am I doing wrong?

Comment: So no one can help me here? I'm dead in the water. :-(

Comment: does the admin server on port 8000 work?

does a system restart help 

does something else run on port 8080?

what happens if you enable wp_debug and php errors?

Answer (score 0):

The `http://locally host:8080` looks fishy in the log. Could you post the extra flags you used for the project as well?